# Trying to flip an image horizontally

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that will run a number of different filters on images. They all work well and output new images, but I'm struggling with this one, that's supposed to flip an image horizontally, ie. do a mirror effect.

The input and output functions of the program are in a different file, whereas the code below is simply to do the flipping of the image. The output works just fine in all other filters, so that's not the issue here.

The code below currently outputs an image, but it's not flipped - it's the original. I've been told that there is something in the code below that simply keeps the image from being mirrored.

I'm stuck. Can you see where the problem is and how I can fix it?

```
void mirror(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])

RGBTRIPLE imageA[height][width];

    for( int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
           RGBTRIPLE temp = imageA[height][width-1-i];
           imageA[height][width-1-i] = image[height][width];
           image[height][width] = temp;
        }
    }

    return;

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `imageA`? (* hint *)

Comment: Jeff, I'd love to hear your thinking. Please elaborate.

Comment: You loop i and j over the dimensions of the image, but you never access any of it.  You only ever modify `image[height][width]`, which is out of range in both dimensions.

Comment: Thank you Chris. How do I fix that?

Comment: Note that the file output is addressed in a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would this work? The problem is that you are counting with i and j, but you aren't referencing the image with them. I'm assuming you are passing image and returning imageA. j is the height so nothing changes there. i is the width so I invert with the width-i.

```
void mirror(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) 

RGBTRIPLE imageA[height][width];

    for( int i = 1; i <= width; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= height; j++)
    {
       imageA[j][width-i] = image[j][i];
    }
}

return;
```

}

Comment: I bet it is the 0 reference. you could try imageA[j+1][width-i+1] = image[j+1][i+1]; Or change the For loops to start at 1 instead of 0 and go to width+1 and height+1

Comment: I tried both options, and a combination of the two, but received DEADLYSIGNAL for all three.

Answer (score 2):

The core of your problem is on this line:

```
for( int i = 0; i < width; i++)
```

It should be:

```
for( int i = 0; i < width/2; i++)
```

Otherwise, you wind up mirroring the image twice, arriving back where you started.

**Updated**

The second problem is that your loop itself has hardcoded references to `height` and `width`, when really meant to use `i` or '`j`.  Also, that `imageA` buffer is not needed at all and is probably another bug by itself, so we can take that out.

And finally, let's swap your inner row loop with the outer column loop.  It makes the algorithm more obvious as "mirroring each line".

Here's the final loop as it should be:

```
void mirror(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for( int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        // mirror the line at row j
        for(int i = 0; i < width/2; i++)
        {
           // swap the left side pixel with the right side pixel
           RGBTRIPLE temp = image[j][width-1-i];  // temp = right side pixel
           image[j][width-1-i] = image[j][i];     // right side pixel = left side pixel
           image[j][i] = temp;                    // left side pixel gets original right pixel value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you selbie. Unfortunately it still outputs the original image.

Comment: Do you see any alternate options/reasons for why it's not working?